# Bootstrap data-target not working as expected

Tags: html, jquery, css, bootstrap-5

I am trying to use bootstrap data-target similar as the code sample below. The data is not loading while clicking the toggle menu.

```
<html xmlns.th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0,minimum-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" th:href="@{/webjars/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css}">
    <script type="text/javascript" th:src="@{/webjars/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" th:src="@{/webjars/jquery/jquery.min.js}"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div>
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-dark navbar-dark">
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav">
                        <li class="navbar-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" th:href="@{/menu1}">Menu1</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="navbar-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" th:href="@{/menu2}">Menu2</a>
                        </li>   
                    </ul>                   
                </div>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I am using jQuery 3.6.0 and bootstrap version 5.0.1

Comment: Bootstrap-5 uses data-bs-toggle and data-bs-target (with bs in the middle). Bootstrap-4 uses data-toggle and data-target.

Comment: Thanks. It works after changing to data-bs-toggle and data-bs-target.